# FireBase: How to modify the object in database?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using AngularFire. Following is the structure of database:

```
supermarket = {
    name : "Food Market",
    products : [
       {name : "Chocolates"}
       {name : "Fruits"}
    ]

 }
```

I wanna push a vegetable object in products array. How can i do this in firebase?

Comment: Read this page first: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html. Then write the code to fit your requirement. If you have problem with that, post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve of what you tried.

Comment: Indeed, this is covered in the guide. Make a sync array to products/ rather than supermarket. Also, don't nest data if you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Stated in Angular Firebase doc for arrays - 
As the array is synchronized with server data and being modified concurrently by the client, it is possible to lose track of the fluid array indices and corrupt the data by manipulating the wrong records. Therefore, the placement of items in the list should never be modified directly by using array methods like push() or splice().

Thus you can not use push() or splice().
Firebase gives its own way of adding items to arrays using $add(item) method.
It internally makes sure that the sync is handled in this concurrent environment.

In your case -
If your model which gets sync with firebase server is

```
    supermarket = {
      name : "Food Market",
      products : [
           {name : "Chocolates"}
           {name : "Fruits"}
      ]
    }
```

You get access to this product array array using a firebase ref.

```
    //create a synchronized array
    $scope.products = $firebaseArray(ref);

    //adding new item to the array
    $scope.products.$add({
     {name : "vegetables"} 
   });
```

Comment: but this will add to supermarket object instead of pushing it in inside products array

Comment: How is it being referenced to products array?

Comment: $scope.products will reference to supermarket object and doing add will push an object to supermarket object instead of products array

Comment: there is a weird object name and i dont know how to create reference to it